# Returning multiple values as single value from lookup in informatica cloud

Tags: cloud, informatica

I am passing emp_id to lookup as argument. I just want to return first name and last name from lookup in single column(i.e. full_name).

We can achieve this in informatica powercenter by concatinating two values. Can somebody tell me how to achieve this in informatica cloud.

Return port should work like this.

Full_name(Return port)=concat(first_name,last_name)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is your lookup data in a database or on SalesForce?

If the lookup data is in a database , create a view on the lookup table with the data you require.

If the lookup data is on SalesForce, create a SalesForce Object field with the concatenated value. Make it invisible on the UI.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** In unconnected lookup first override the query like:

```
select empid,firstname||lastname from emp order by
```

`Order by` will ignore the default order by clause creation by informatica.

**2.** Now return that port to expression transformation and extract the firstname and last name values.

Comment: query : select empid , firstname ||','|| lastname  from emp order by--

Comment: you can concatenate multiple ports in lookup override and extract them in expression transformation.

Comment: You can consider editing your own answer instead of commenting it